# Can't connect to Websocket from a Backend Application

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot, websocket, nestjs

I'm trying to create a proof of concept and send a message to Websocket made with Spring everytime a hit a specific endpoint in an Api Rest made with NestJs.

For this, I created the following controller using Nest.js

```
import { Controller, Get, Render, Post, Body, ConfigurableModuleBuilder } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @Render('index')
  getHello(): HelloWorldDTO {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Post('/error2')
  @Render('error2')
  async getError(@Body() body: any) {
    try {
      // Crea una conexión WebSocket hacia el servidor externo
      const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/flow');
      // Crea un cliente STOMP sobre la conexión SockJS
      const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

      const connectPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Conexión establecida: ' + frame);
            resolve();
          },
          function (error) {
            console.error('Error de conexión: ' + error);
            reject(error);
          },
        );
      });
      await connectPromise;
      const from = 'test';
      const text = 'test';
      stompClient.send(
        '/app/flow',
        {},
        JSON.stringify({ name: from, message: text }),
      );
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function () {});
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  @Get('/error')
  @Render('error')
  getErrorGet(): HelloWorldDTO {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

But when I hit the endpoint /error2, I get the following error:

`ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/flow`

But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to implement more or less the same logic I used for a html client who can connect and, in fact, send and receive messages.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var stompClient = null;
            function connect() {
                var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/flow');
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
                        showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                    });
                });
            }
            
            function disconnect() {
                if(stompClient != null) {
                    stompClient.disconnect();
                }
                setConnected(false);
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
            
            function sendMessage() {
                console.log("enviando mensaje");
                var from = "test";
                var text = "test";
                stompClient.send("/app/flow", {}, 
                  JSON.stringify({'name':from, 'message':text}));
            }
            
            $(document).ready(function(){
                connect();
            });
            

        </script>
```

Here is the Websocket controller

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/flow")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return new Greeting("Hola " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }
}
```

And here is the Websocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        //registry.addEndpoint("/flow").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/flow").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

I tried with different libraries to connect the API Rest with the Websocket with not luck, I'm expecting to being able to send a message and the html client to receive it everytime i hit the POST endpoint.

Comment: You should probably use this connection url `wss://localhost:8080/websocket/flow`